# Drawing to indicate algorithms

Tags: diagrams, algorithms, technical-drawing

I'm looking for one good drawing so as to symbolise algorithms. The idea is to use this drawing like one symbolic icon.

Have you some ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried a google image search for `algorithm icon`?

Comment: Yes. I didn't found anything interesting.

Comment: Any requirements, how large it should be?

Comment: How about a flowchart image (see google)? Flowcharts are out of date as programming tools but do say "algorithm" visually.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker : That's a good idea.

Comment: @Count Zero : I will need two square versions : 16 and 32 points.

Comment: @projetmbc: Ugh... That's really an icon. Maybe you should create a drawing on your own in an editor and export to `tikz`. Or, if you want to skip that step, you can look up as a starting point something from [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/) and simplify/reduce that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have more free time the coming week. I'll post here one proposition if I make somethin not to ugly.

Comment: As it stands, I feel this is probably off topic: it's essentially a graphic design question.